# What happens if Bardin’s bomb inventory is already full when Ingenious Ordnance generates a new bomb?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

I have a question about the Outcast Engineer talent, Ingenious Ordnance, that was introduced in [*Vermintide 2*’s Patch 5.2.0 (2023-12-13)](https://steamcommunity.com/games/552500/announcements/detail/3861337227494099516).

> 'Leading Shots' replaced by new talent 'Ingenious Ordnance' - Bardin creates a bomb every 80 seconds and explosives no longer deal friendly fire damage.

I want to manage my bombs effectively with Ingenious Ordnance and know when it is optimal to keep them, use them, or share them with my teammates. My question is:

**What happens if Bardin’s bomb inventory is already full when Ingenious Ordnance generates a new bomb?**
Does the new bomb immediately appear in my inventory after I throw or give away a bomb? Or do I have to wait another 80 seconds for the cooldown to end?

Comment: I found videos showing the talent only work until your bombs are full. Once one is thrown, it starts the timer again.  I assume if you gave a bomb away it would also begin the timer.  The only thing I couldn't tell is how this works between the two bomb types.  One video seemed to show it would focus on whatever bomb type you had equipped first, and then once you reached 3 of those bombs, it would start crafting the opposite type - but I don't remember how this games inventory management worked (I thought you could carry at most 2 bombs [3 when using this career for Bardin])